# How to best way to construct a static class member in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor, static

So simply put, I have a class Foo with a Foo() constructor.

Another class Bar which contains a static member of class Foo: the Foo member is being initialized (but not constructed).

What's the best way to construct the static member, in other words where and how should I make sure the constructor is called on the static member?

Should I turn to singleton?

```cpp
// In demo.h

class Foo {
  Foo() {
    // doing important stuff in there
  }
};

class Bar {
   static Foo foo;
};

// In demo.cpp
Foo Bar :: foo = Foo();


void main() {
  Bar bar;

  // bar.foo is not constructed yet. How to do that?
}
```

Comment: what "best" do you mean? "best" like "it works" ?

Comment: Just a nice way to do it

Comment: "// bar.foo is not constructed yet. How to do that?" unclear. You want `bar.foo` to be not constructed yet? Or is it your observation? How?

Comment: `Foo Bar :: foo = Foo();` is a nice way, no?

Comment: you should clarify the question. "bar.foo is not constructed yet." is wrong and in your example there is no way to tell the difference. It sounds like you made some observations or encountered issues on some other code and while creating a simplified example removed the issue.

Comment: "_bar.foo is not constructed yet_": That's wrong. It is constructed. Non-local static storage duration variables are initialized before `main` is entered, or at least before the first use of the variable in `main`. That is _always_ guaranteed. Btw. `void` is not a return type for `main` that is permitted by the standard. It must _always_ be declared to return `int`.

Comment: `Bar::foo` will be constructed in the code you posted. You should post some code that proves you are dealing with an unconstructed object. It can happen, but not in the way you've described above.

Comment: You should come up with two or three possibilities, then choose the *best* according to your definition of *best*.

Comment: You're right. I didi a real that shown it works. So I am going to investigate with the actual (larger) code. And btw, should I remove the question?

Comment: `class Bar { static inline Foo foo; };` and now its defined in the class.

Comment: I suspect (may be incorrectly) that you are actually dealing with SIOF https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order but your example code has removed it. If so, read up that FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to what you seem to believe, what you're doing right now should invoke `Foo`'s ctor correctly.

You are doing a bit more than is really needed though. You could reduce this:

```cpp
Foo Bar :: foo = Foo();
```

To just:

```cpp
Foo Bar::foo;
```

As it was before, you were (in theory) default constructing a temporary object, then copy constructing `Bar::foo` from that temporary. I don't see much point in that (though a sane compiler won't normally do that--it'll just default construct the object directly, so your extra code was just adding visual noise).

Comment: "_you were (in theory) default constructing a temporary object, then copy constructing Bar::foo from that temporary_": That's not the case anymore since C++17. They are now completely identical in meaning, even in theory.

Comment: @user17732522: True--and it's certainly possible he's using C++17 or newer, but at least based on what I see, there's no way to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for this advice (I am using c++ 11 on embedded system)